# Is there a difference between directly assigning a final variable and assigning a final variable in the constructor?

Tags: java, initialization, final

is there a difference between these two initializations of the final variable `value`?

```
class Test {
    final int value = 7;
    Test() {}
}
```

and

```
class Test {
    final int value;
    Test() {
        value = 7;
    }
}
```

--

**EDIT:** A more complex example, involving subclasses. "0" is printed to stdout in this case, but 7 is printed if i assign the value directly.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

class TestBox extends JCheckBox {

    final int value;

    public TestBox() {
        value = 7;
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener l) {
        System.out.println(value);
        super.addPropertyChangeListener(l); 
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        panel.add(new TestBox());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This example is a bit obscure: where is `addPropertyChangeListener()` called?

Comment: @Viruzzo I suspect it's called within the Constructor of JCheckBox or JComponent or ... The code is a stripped down example of a custom JCheckBox-Component I'm currently building which has some special properties (like some more properties for which I want to be able to register PropertyChangeListeners)

Comment: For the constructor of the superclass to call a method of the subclass it would be a mistake, if at all possible. This example is probably flawed due to the use of JFrame and possible concurrency issues.

Comment: @Viruzzo addPropertyChangeListener is a virtual method (as are all methods in Java) so the superclasses Constructor will call TextBox.addPropertyChangeListener if it calls addPropertyChangeListener at all. Or do I get something wrong? What concurrency issues are you thinking of, regarding the AWT Event Thread (since I'm not spawning any other threads)?

Comment: The case value = 0 is only possible is TestBox.addPropertyChangeListener() is called inside TestBox.super(), and that seems like a very strange behaviour, or... Have you tried using single braces instead of double ones in the JFrame and JPanel initialization? I can't verify right now, but it could be meaningful.

Comment: I altered the second example to be a bit less obscure. Same effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried with a very simple example and yes, when value is accessed in the parent's constructor it is unitialized (as it should be), *unless* it's final **and** initialized when declared. The process is that described by EJP, but with a #0 step: finals are initialized with the specified value, if any.

Answer (score 4):

There is differece in byte-code level:

Source code:

```
  final int value;

  public TestBox() {
      value = 7;
  }
```

Produces following code from `addPropertyChangeListener`:

```
   0:   getstatic       #3; 
   3:   aload_0
   4:   getfield        #2; 
   7:   invokevirtual   #4;
```

And source code:

```
final int value = 7;

public TestBox() {      
}
```

Produces the following code from `addPropertyChangeListener`:

```
   0:   getstatic       #3; 
   3:   bipush  7
   5:   invokevirtual   #4;
```

So there is a small difference. But not practical.

Seems that compiler can handle a final variable as a constant if it is intialized in definition statement. Of course different compilers may do it different way.

Comment: Wuow. Thanks for the disassembly. That `small difference` actually blows up a whole component in my software (it's only a stripped down example that I posted here).

Comment: blows up? That is strange, because functionality should be same. Only unrelevant speed or memory usage differences should occur.

Comment: In the complete code there is a PropertyChangeSupport-Object which is not yet created when the addPropertyChangeListener()-method is invoked. I'm now accessing it only if it is not null, since otherwise I get an NPE when creating the CheckBox. I just wondered how this can be.

Answer (score 1):

A common misinterpretation of a final variable is that it can't change its value. The actual meaning of the final modifier (JLS 4.5.4) is that "a final variable may only be assigned to once".

You've run into one of the situations where it is possible to evaluate a so called "blank final" (declared, but not yet assigned) variable, so that it evaluates to the default value for the specified datatype, even if its later assigned a different value.

Answer (score 0):

Other that in the second case you could assign a different value based in which constructor was called or which parameters were passed to it, **NO.**

Comment: does that always hold, i.e. for subclasses?

Comment: @scravy: subclasses constructor will have to call super(...), which will initialize the final field based on the argument passed to super(...). So yes, it holds for subclasses

Comment: I've added another example involving subclasses, which I absolutely can't explain then (other than that there is something strange going on with JCheckBox).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. The only difference is the order used to initialize the fields: fields initialized directly are initialized before the ones initialized in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any difference. But the value you need in it might help you in decide which to use.

1. If the variable is final and assigned with fixed value in constructor then no need to assign it in constructor.
2. If the variable is final and assigned with different values, passed as argument, in constructor then you need to assign it in constructor.

Mostly the first case is used. Because as far as I know final varibales are nothing but the constants.

Answer (score 0):

A constructor executes in the following order:

1. super() is called.
2. Local variables are initialized and anonymous initializer blocks {} are called.
3. The code in the constructor itself is called. Note that if the constructor explicitly calls super() itself this is taken care of under #1.

So the answer to your question is that the initialization would be moved from #2 in the declaration-with-initializer version to #3 in the initialize-in-constructor version. However unless you have anonymous initializer blocks {} or possibly fields that are initialized using prior initializations of other fields, it would be impossible to tell the difference.

Comment: so `super()` (#1) is even called before the direct assignment `final int value = 7;` (#2)?

Comment: @scravy (#1) yes (#2) fields, not variables but you get the idea; initializer blocks are the same as static initializer blocks, but for instances: basically you put some code between {} outside any method, and it gets called at step #2.

Comment: @EJP I've added another example involving a sub-class calling super. If i got you right, `super()` should be called before initialization of `value` either way, however I do see 0 once, and 7 if i assign the variable directly.